# WebStorm 2019. Problem with connection of JavaScript debug mode

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, protocols, webstorm

I have a next problem relation with as module JavaScript debug of WebStorm 2019. When I try to config my application into debug mode on my JavaScript modules, which  have written on EcmaScript 6 standard of JavaScript languages. In below I have a next configure on debug mode of my JavaScript application:

Name of module: IndexPage
URL: http://localhost:63342/MatrixDraw/index.html
Browser: Chrome

Warning message: Waiting for connection http://localhost:63342. Please ensure that the browser started successfully on remote port debugging mode...

Warning message for waiting connection:

[image]

The file of mark up `index.html` was included with help `bootstrap.js` module. Just one file which I need to include into mark up stage data. And according to that file I have included in treedown stage technology data roots of chain dependencies of CommonJS ideologic.

How I can resolve that problem with debug mode?

P.S: Because in last versions of WebStorm (2014, 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018) were working successfully on JavaScript debug mode and Node.js debug mode. And I have already to install and to config a module of plugin JetBrains into Chrome browser and activated that.

Comment: 2019 is not yet publically available, it's a very new unstable version (first EAPs can be expected next year). So I'm unsure what version you are actually using. What build number is it?

Comment: I am using a version:
WebStorm 2018.2.2
Build #WS-182.4129.32, built on August 21, 2018
Licensed to Kostiantyn Halantsev
Subscription is active until April 22, 2019
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Comment: debugging definitely works in 2018.2.2, I'm not aware of any issues. Please try closing all Chrome instances before starting the debugger - does the issue persist?

Comment: After closing and rerun my Javascript debug mode, I have got a next error message: 

Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960 for more details.

Comment: this warning is shown by browser and is likely related to your code; it  has nothing to do with the IDE debugger

Comment: My code, directly, has written on ES6 by Javascript module with including standard of file data on CommonJS. So, the situation about my code or any kind of problem which are specifying on Syntax Error, coludn't be. Because Engine of browser doesn't has a that Error like Syntax. My console output of browser is empty. And in that is really difficult situation.

Comment: we don't use anything of this kind anywhere in the debugger code. what Chrome version do you use? Try disabling all Chrome extensions - does the issue persist?

Comment: I have used browser Chrome 70.0.3538.67. So I know, that ES6 standard for Javascript using, is working on Chrome version from 61.*. So I think is trouble with a WebStorm module of debug, but how I can resolve that, without change or downgrade version of WebStorm module?

Comment: this has nothing to do with webStorm, as well as with es6 standard. This is a runtime warning reported by browser, caused by either your code or one of chrome extensions being used

Comment: I think, that problem relation with ES6. But how I can resolve that problem, I need to make debug mode on javascript application and in result I have a problem which is relation with a ES6 standard? I mean, what I need to do?

Comment: this is not about ES6, but about deprecated Web API methods. And this is just a warning anyway, it shouldn't normallty prevent your app from working (and you should be able to debug your app despite this warning)

Comment: No, it's, deffinitely, depened from a core of WebStorm module javascript debug and Chrome browser engines or another engines of browsers.

Comment: My Browser Chrome-DEV and Firefox-DeveloperEdition has version like: Firefox 64.0b10, and  Chrome_72.0.3610.2, directly. So according to that, browsers has to work on javascrip languages of version like ES6 and ES6+ and ESNext. But in fact browsers debugger mode and WebStorm 2018 version javascript Debugger it is not working and ignore anything of event check point on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this file:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.2\options\other.xml
```

If that didn't work, in addition to the above, remove this file:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.2\options\web-browsers.xml
```

As always remember to take backups of your files.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exist in **WebStorm 2022.3.1**, I was trying to Debug my Vue app. So I did two changes after running app using **npm**:

1. Go to the WebStorm preference > Tools > Web Browsers and Preview >
   click on '+' to Add a new Chrome profile > Give Name **ChromeVueDev** >
   Click Edit and input Command Line Options
   **--remote-allow-origins=*** and Enable checkbox **Use custom user data directory** > Apply changes
   [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9nFs.png)
2. Next you have to create a new Run/Debug Configurations > Click on '+' to Add > Select JavaScript Debug > Give name and URL where your Vue app is running > Select newly created browser profile (i.e ChromeVueDev) from the Browser dropdown.
   [Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwhc6.png)

After that you will be able to run your configuration in debug mode. Once you run, it will open a new instance of Chrome where your application will be rendered